# Insert/update to multiple DB connections in loop using JDBC PreparedStatement

Tags: jdbc

I am working on a program which is supposed to do inserts/updates to a DB table using JDBC program. Inserts/updates need to happen to 2 separate DB instances. There is an input XML file which is read by program, input file has about 1800 records. For each record, I need to do updates as per record read from XML file if record already exists in DB. Do insert otherwise. I am using below program to do the work and it doesn't give consistent results when I execute the program. Looks like PreparedStatement for DB2 in if and else section is actually pointing to DB1 because after successful insert/update to DB1 for the first record, it fails to do the same for DB2 saying primary key violation but DB2 is a different connection and I don't have the record there so primary key violation for DB2 doesn't make sense! Seems that connection information is getting mixed somehow.
Below is how the program looks. I have given only relevant sections of the program. PreparedStatment2 and PreparedStatement4 are not giving expected results. Please note that I have verified connection2 and that's indeed pointing to DB2 and not DB1. Weird thing is that every time I execute the program, it starts working for the record which didn't work in last execution so each program execution gets me past the issue of 1 record in loop and start giving the problem for next one! Can someone help me understanding why PreparedStatement2 and 4 are not working as expected for DB2?

Thanks,
Chanchal

```
Connection connection1 = null;
Connection connection2 = null;
Statement statement = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement1 = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement2 = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement3 = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement4 = null;
ResultSet resultSet1 = null;
try
{
    connection1 = DriverManager.getConnection(properties.getProperty(RT_DB1_URL), properties.getProperty(RT_DB1_USER), properties.getProperty(RT_DB1_PWD));

    connection2 = DriverManager.getConnection(properties.getProperty(RT_DB2_URL), properties.getProperty(RT_DB2_USER), properties.getProperty(RT_DB2_PWD));
//Get list
for (int temp = 0; temp < list.getLength(); temp++) {
    //Get fieldValueA,fieldValueB, fieldValueC, fieldValueD values from a XML file
    //Find if record exists in DB
    String selectQuery = "select * from table_x where fieldA='" + fieldValueA + "'";
    resultSet1 = statement.executeQuery(selectQuery);
    if(resultSet1.next()){
              // Update table
              String query = "update table_x set fieldB = ?,fieldC = ?,fieldD = ? where fieldA = ?";

              preparedStatement1 = connection1.prepareStatement(query);
              preparedStatement2 = connection2.prepareStatement(query);
              preparedStatement1.setString(1, fieldValueB);
              preparedStatement1.setString(2, fieldValueC);
              preparedStatement1.setString(3, fieldValueD);
              preparedStatement1.setString(4, fieldValueA);

              int k = preparedStatement1.executeUpdate(); 
              logger.info("Records successfully updated in RT DB1 for fieldA=" + fieldValueA);
              //Closing the statement as it exceeds oracle cursor limit otherwise with default cursor limit of 300            
              if (preparedStatement1 != null) preparedStatement1.close();
              preparedStatement2.setString(1, fieldValueB);
              preparedStatement2.setString(2, fieldValueC);
              preparedStatement2.setString(3, fieldValueD);
              preparedStatement2.setString(4, fieldValueA);

              int k = preparedStatement2.executeUpdate(); 
              logger.info("Records successfully updated in RT DB2 for fieldA=" + fieldValueA);
              //Closing the statement as it exceeds oracle cursor limit otherwise with default cursor limit of 300            
              if (preparedStatement2 != null) preparedStatement2.close();       

    }
    else{
              //Insert to the table

              String queryInsert = "insert into table_x(fieldA,fieldB,fieldC,fieldD)";
              queryInsert = queryInsert + " values(?,?,?,?)";
              preparedStatement3 = connection1.prepareStatement(queryInsert);
              preparedStatement4 = connection2.prepareStatement(queryInsert);
              preparedStatement3.setString(1, fieldValueA);
              preparedStatement3.setString(2, fieldValueB);
              preparedStatement3.setString(3, fieldValueC);
              preparedStatement3.setString(4, fieldValueD);

              int k = preparedStatement3.executeUpdate(); 
              logger.info("Records successfully inserted in RT DB1 for fieldA=" + fieldValueA);
              if (preparedStatement3 != null) preparedStatement3.close();
              preparedStatement4.setString(1, fieldValueA);
              preparedStatement4.setString(2, fieldValueB);
              preparedStatement4.setString(3, fieldValueC);
              preparedStatement4.setString(4, fieldValueD);

              int k = preparedStatement4.executeUpdate(); 
              logger.info("Records successfully inserted in RT DB2 for fieldA=" + fieldValueA);
              if (preparedStatement4 != null) preparedStatement4.close();   
    } // End loop

} catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally{
            try { if (resultSet1 != null) resultSet1.close(); } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();};
            try { if (statement != null) statement.close(); } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();};
            try { if (connection1 != null) connection1.close(); } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();};
            try { if (connection2 != null) connection2.close(); } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();};               
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is fine, to create the prepared statements before the loop. So they can be reused within every loop. Also you can do batch processing and send all data to the DBs after running all. If there are some 1000 records, it might sense to flush the batch earlier, but 1800 records can be processed within a batch in one time.  I could not test this code, but I hope it gives you some hints.

```
Connection connection1 = null;
Connection connection2 = null;
Statement statement = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement1 = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement2 = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement3 = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement4 = null;
ResultSet resultSet1 = null;
try
{
connection1 = DriverManager.getConnection(properties.getProperty(RT_DB1_URL), properties.getProperty(RT_DB1_USER), properties.getProperty(RT_DB1_PWD));

connection2 = DriverManager.getConnection(properties.getProperty(RT_DB2_URL), properties.getProperty(RT_DB2_USER), properties.getProperty(RT_DB2_PWD));

// Update table
String query = "update table_x set fieldB = ?,fieldC = ?,fieldD = ? where fieldA = ?";
preparedStatement1 = connection1.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement2 = connection2.prepareStatement(query);

String queryInsert = "insert into table_x(fieldA,fieldB,fieldC,fieldD)";
queryInsert = queryInsert + " values(?,?,?,?)";
preparedStatement3 = connection1.prepareStatement(queryInsert);
preparedStatement4 = connection2.prepareStatement(queryInsert);
    

//Get list
for (int temp = 0; temp < list.getLength(); temp++) {
//Get fieldValueA,fieldValueB, fieldValueC, fieldValueD values from a XML file
//Find if record exists in DB
String selectQuery = "select * from table_x where fieldA='" + fieldValueA + "'";


resultSet1 = statement.executeQuery(selectQuery);
if(resultSet1.next()){
          
          preparedStatement1.setString(1, fieldValueB);
          preparedStatement1.setString(2, fieldValueC);
          preparedStatement1.setString(3, fieldValueD);
          preparedStatement1.setString(4, fieldValueA);

          preparedStatement1.addBatch(); 
          
          logger.info("Records successfully added RT DB1 for fieldA=" + fieldValueA);
                      
          preparedStatement2.setString(1, fieldValueB);
          preparedStatement2.setString(2, fieldValueC);
          preparedStatement2.setString(3, fieldValueD);
          preparedStatement2.setString(4, fieldValueA);

          preparedStatement2.addBatch(); 
          logger.info("Records successfully added in RT DB2 for fieldA=" + fieldValueA);
            

}
else{
          //Insert to the table

          preparedStatement3.setString(1, fieldValueA);
          preparedStatement3.setString(2, fieldValueB);
          preparedStatement3.setString(3, fieldValueC);
          preparedStatement3.setString(4, fieldValueD);

          preparedStatement3.addBatch(); 
          logger.info("Records successfully added  RT DB1 for fieldA=" + fieldValueA);
          if (preparedStatement3 != null) preparedStatement3.close();
          preparedStatement4.setString(1, fieldValueA);
          preparedStatement4.setString(2, fieldValueB);
          preparedStatement4.setString(3, fieldValueC);
          preparedStatement4.setString(4, fieldValueD);

          preparedStatement4.addBatch(); 
          
} // End loop

// now, we are flushing the batch to the DBs
int[] k1 = preparedStatement1.executeBatch();
int[] k2 = preparedStatement2.executeBatch();
int[] k3 = preparedStatement3.executeBatch();
int[] k4 = preparedStatement4.executeBatch();
logger.info("updated " + String.format("%,d",k1.lenght) + " Records in DB1 and " + String.format("%,d",k2.lenght) + " inserted " + String.format("%,d",k3.length) + " Records in DB1 and " + String.format("%,d",k4.length) + " in DB2");


} catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
  finally{
      
        try { if preparedStatement1 != null ) preparedStatement1 } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();};
        try { if preparedStatement2 != null ) preparedStatement2 } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();};
        try { if preparedStatement3 != null ) preparedStatement3 } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();};
        try { if preparedStatement4 != null ) preparedStatement4 } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();};
      
        try { if (resultSet1 != null) resultSet1.close(); } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();};
        try { if (statement != null) statement.close(); } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();};
        try { if (connection1 != null) connection1.close(); } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();};
        try { if (connection2 != null) connection2.close(); } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();};               

  }
)
```